# $\frac{x+y}{xy+1}$ when $-1<x,y<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've been reading C.C. Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, and one of the excercises there is proving that the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:-1<x<1\}$ forms an abelian group under the operation $x*y=\frac{x+y}{xy+1}$.

The way the question is phrased doesn't require you to show that $*$ is indeed an operation on the set (it takes it for granted), but I'm having trouble with showing that to myself.

It's well-defined, because $xy+1=0$ implies $xy=-1$, which is impossible for $x,y$ in the domain.

How do I prove its closure, though? I need to show that whenever $-1<x,y<1$, we also get that $-1<x*y<1$.

I broke it into different scenarios- $x,y>0$, $x<0$ and $y>0$, or $x,y<0$.
I left out the case when $x=0$ or $y=0$ because it's simple to check, and of course, I didn't have to include ($x>0$ and $y<0$) because $x$ and $y$ are symmetric.

How would one go on from here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question _does_ ask you to do that, unless it's explicitly noted in the question (I don't own this book).

Comment: It says "Prove that each of the following sets, with the indicated operation, is an abelian group", and it refers you to instructions on how to prove each property of the group. The instructions don't include the closure, so I assumed you can skip that step (I could be wrong).

Comment: To me this implicitly includes the verification of closure. If I faced this problem, I would be sure to, first of all, check if the set given in the problem is closed under the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $$-1<x<1\ \ \&\ \ -1<y<1$$ Therefore,

- $x<1\ \&\ y<1$ implies that $x-1<0$ and $y-1<0$. Thus $$(x-1)(y-1)>0\Rightarrow xy-x-y+1>0\Rightarrow \frac{x+y}{1+xy}<1.$$
- $x>-1\ \&\ y>-1$ implies that $x+1>0$ and $y+1>0$. Thus $$(x+1)(y+1)>0\Rightarrow xy+x+y+1>0\Rightarrow x+y>-(1+xy)\Rightarrow\frac{x+y}{1+xy}>-1.$$

and you obtain the desired result. (Notice that $xy+1>0$).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an after-the-fact answer to "what's 'really' going on here?": The hyperbolic tangent $\tanh:(\mathbf{R}, +) \to \bigl((-1, 1), *\bigr)$ is a group isomorphism, thanks to the identity
$$
\tanh(u + v) = \frac{\tanh u + \tanh v}{1 + \tanh u \tanh v},\qquad \text{$u$, $v$ real.}
$$
(This implicitly shows $(-1, 1)$ is closed under $*$, if you buy that $\tanh$ is bijective and a sum of real numbers is a real number.)

Comment: I have noticed the similarity of the formula given with a formula for the sum of (trigonometric) tangents, but I didn't know hyperbolic functions have such nice sum formula. You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you have to show that $|x+y|<|xy+1|$. It's pretty easy to see $xy>-1$, so $|xy+1|=xy+1$. Now if $|x+y|\geq0$, then $|x+y|<|xy+1|$ is equivalent to $0<(x-1)(y-1)$. Similarly for $|x+y|<0$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice shortcut if you note that $z\in(-1,1)\iff1-z^2>0$. Then:

$$1-(x*y)^2=1-\left(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right)^2=\frac{(1+xy)^2-(x+y)^2}{(1+xy)^2}=\frac{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}{(1+xy)^2}$$

and the result drops out quite nicely from here.